# If statement without repetitive selector?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

With this simple example..

```
if ($('.target').is(':hidden')) {
    $('.target').show();
}  else {
    $('.target').hide();
}
```

I'm curious if it can be optimized, perhaps something like:

```
if ($('.target').is(':hidden')) {
   .show();
} else {
   .hide();
}
```

Or $(this)..

```
if ($('.target').is(':hidden')) {
   $(this).show();
} else {
   $(this).hide();
}
```

---

*Not necessarily related strictly to this example which I know I could use toggle for.. This is just about the simplest if/else example I thought of for use as example.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, with a variable

```
var element = $('.target');

if (element.is(':hidden')) {
    element.show();
}  else {
    element.hide();
}
```

and jQuery has a nifty `toggle()` method that does the same thing

```
$('.target').toggle();
```

Going of the deep end, you can also do stuff like this

```
(function(el) {
    el[el.is(':hidden')?'show':'hide']();
})($('.target'));
```

And a number of other ways

Comment: @SterlingArcher - Sure, lets call it that  ?

Comment: I guess show hide was a poor example, but it was only meant to be a simple example of an if else statement as I mentioned.  Not necessarily related to toggle.  Thanks.

Comment: I have never liked the `toggle()` function, you can actually toggle the wrong way if your not very careful.

Comment: @Edward - Uh, what! How would that be possible exactly ?

Comment: I had an app that paused media playback using `toggle()` when it had a notification and started playing again once you read it, of course more than one notification would trigger the playback again.

Comment: @Edward - jQuery's `toggle()` only toggles the visibility of an element, the toggle function you're referring to was removed from jQuery some time ago

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those will work for you. You'll have to save the target as a variable first.

```
var $target = $('.target');
if ($target.is(':hidden')) {
  $target.show();
} else {
  $target.hide();
}
```

If you really want to keep things short, try this:

```
var $target = $('.target');
$target[$target.is(':hidden') ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

But really, just use the `toggle` jQuery method.

```
$('.target').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are just toggling between showing and hiding an element.  JQuery has a method for this.  Its just called .toggle() --- http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

So if you're just trying to show and hide something you can say

```
$('.target').toggle();
```

Alternately, if there is more logic involved, it is advantageous to cache your jQuery variables as every time you wrap a selector in $ you are rewrapped that element or re-traversing the DOM.

So:

```
var target =  $('.target');
if(target.is(':hidden')) {
   target.show();
} else {
   target.hide();
}
```